# How to put images in a customlist that's limited in size in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm new here, so I hope you don't too angry if my question is bad. 
Before I ask my question, I wanna say, that I've tried searching on Google and here before writing this questions, but I didn't find a solution for my problem.

I'm trying to make a CustomList, which is limited in size; The activity also have a searchview.
The problem is that when I run the emulator and wanna see the activity with the list it gives me these errors:

```
11-16 23:58:33.520 2115-2115/com.example.hh.do2get E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 23:58:33.520 2115-2115/com.example.hh.do2get E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.hh.do2get, PID: 2115
11-16 23:58:33.520 2115-2115/com.example.hh.do2get E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

There is more, but I don't think it's relevant

**What I'm expecting**

The activities I'm working should do the following: You've a searchview where you write something and click on search then in the other activity only relevant results should appear, it's like Google in a way.

**What I've done**
I've made a java class for the customlistadapter then in one of the 2 activities I've used `Intent` to send the some data to the other activity, which is the letters somebody writes. Then in the other activity I make a string array and try to put it in the list, but this doesn't work, because (I think) the `Intent` I've made doesn't send any data.

So here is my code:

This is my CustomListAdapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final Integer[] imgid;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, int layout, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
    super(context, layout, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_forside, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
    return rowView;

 };
}
```

This is my first activity, where one writes something and click on the button:

```
public class Forside extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Liste{

CustomListAdapter listAdapter;
EditText filterText;

ImageButton sog;
EditText sogefelt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forside);
    filterText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sogefelt);
    ListView itemList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, annoncer, imageId);
    sog = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sog);
    sog.setOnClickListener(this);
    sogefelt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sogefelt);

    itemList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}


public void onClick (View v){
    if (v == sog){
        String søgeord = sogefelt.getText().toString();
        ArrayList<String> resultater = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String i: annoncer) {
            if (i.contains(søgeord))
                resultater.add(i);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Sogeresultater.class);
        intent.putExtra("søg", resultater.toArray(new String[resultater.size()]));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

Here is activity that should filter the list and show only relevant results:

```
public class Sogeresultater extends ActionBarActivity implements Liste{

ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
EditText filterText;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);


    final String[] søgestreng = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("søg");
    System.out.println(søgestreng);


    filterText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sogefelt);
    ListView itemList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,søgestreng);

    itemList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Sogeresultater.this.listAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

When I started making the activities I used ListView, but because I needed to put images I had to use CustomList. I've this problem (question) is due to the searchview, which I need. I've seen many examples on the internet where CustomList is used but without a searchview/search bar.

Please, if this question is bad, tell me why.

Comment: The null pointer indicates that you are trying to call setText() on a null TextView.  It's hard to say more without line numbers from the stack trace.  Are you sure that all of your TextViews actually exist in your layouts?  findViewById will happily return null of one of them doesn't exist (e.g. you are trying to fetch a TextView using an ID that doesn't exist in that layout).

Comment: What can I do to make it easier for you to help me?

Comment: Well, take a look at the actual stack trace that you are seeing.  It should have class names, method names, and line numbers in it.  That will tell you the exact line of code that is generating an error.  Being that it is a null TextView, I am guessing that it is the `getView()` method in your custom list adapter (that's the only place I see TextViews).  Double check your layout and make sure that both TextViews actually exist  It could help if you posted the layout as well as a full stack trace.

Comment: I think I know the problem. You're right, it's soemthing with the textviews. It's because I have made another activity and the textviews are there. However, this doesn't solve my problem, as I still don't know how to make a customlist with a searchview :(

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell exactly what the issue is without more information, but try this. There may be more errors but this is the current outstanding one:

```
txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
```

You're referencing a null object when you try to call setText. That means that you aren't identifying your TextView correctly, or the system isn't able to find your TextView.

Check if the resource ID's are correct, and then check if CustomListAdapter is being called correctly:

```
TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Comment: Does the layout R.layout.activity_forside contain R.id.item as a TextView, and does it also contain R.id.textView1 as a TextView? Also, which line does the error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference point to? it should tell you.

Comment: R.layout.activity_forside, doesn't contain the textview, it contains an edittext and a listview (where I want to put the pictures). What do I have to change in order to let this work: A searchview and below it a listview with images?

Comment: Right now you're trying to get the TextViews from R.layout.activity_forside, because you've set R.layout.activity_forside to rowView. Make it reflect correctly to what you want.

Comment: I want it to change the titles in the listview, which I've in R.layout.activity_forside

Comment: Try changing rowView to view so that:
TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
TextView extratxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

Comment: The program crashes now and gives me `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`